# Multiple columns in csv

Tags: php, csv, multiple-columns

I'm creating a downloadable csv with php. This is what I have so far:

```
 // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

 // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
 $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

 // output the column headings
 fputcsv($output, array('id', 'role_id', 'parent_id'));

 $list = RoleQuery::create()->find();
 $list = $list->toArray();

 $list = array_values($list);
 // loop over the rows, outputting them
 foreach($list as $fields){
     fputcsv($output, $fields);
 }
```

Just for testing I'm outputting the roles in my database. The problem is that they're all in one column like this:

[image]

How can I make sure that id, role_id and parent_id are in different columns?

Comment: Use software on the client which actually knows how to open csv files? All you need on the server (in this case) is a comma, and you appear to have that.

Comment: I've opened it with Excel and it gave me this result .. Excel knows how to open csv files?

Comment: It is totally up to the reader. In most readers, like Excel or LibreOffice you have several options when you load the file. Yout output could gladly be taken as a multiple coulmn CSV by most readers. However, I would place quotes "" around each cell / column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV data looks fine, but it looks like whatever tool you're using to open the CSV isn't using commas as the delimiter. You could, as davidkonrad suggested, wrap each value in quotes and see if that helps. Usually though, when opening a CSV in Google Docs or Excel, it will ask you how you'd like to delimit, and they typically default to commas.